# Change height of UIView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, height

I have an `UIViewController` with `TableView` which is showed when I pressed `Button` in another `View`. It slides correctly from the bottom of the screen, but I want its height to be half of screen height and stays at the bottom of the screen.

How can I get this?

Here is my code:

**CupsViewController**

This is the code when `Button` is pressed for showing `TableView`.

```
//DirectionViewController is the one that contains TableView
DirectionViewController *directionController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"directionsView"];        

// Position the options at bottom of screen
CGRect optionsFrame = directionController.view.frame;
optionsFrame.origin.x = 0;
optionsFrame.size.width = 320;
optionsFrame.origin.y = 423;

// For the animation, move the view up by its own height.
optionsFrame.origin.y += optionsFrame.size.height;

directionController.view.frame = optionsFrame;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

optionsFrame.origin.y -= optionsFrame.size.height;
directionController.view.frame = optionsFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:directionController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the options frame height to half of screen size in your animation code.

Hope this is what you are looking for

https://github.com/slysid/iOS/tree/master/HalfTable

/Bharath

Comment: I want it to stay at the bottom of the screen, too.

Comment: Can you check the project from GITHUB and see is that something like that you are trying to do?

Comment: I can't find how to import your project into XCode. Do I have to copy all files by hand?

Comment: I have added a tableviewcontroller and it works fine. https://github.com/slysid/iOS/tree/master/HalfTable

Comment: https://github.com/slysid/iOS go to this location and you can see download option in bottom right hand corner. You can download the project and open it in Xcode